# Why does gluProject not give the correct screen space coordinates with LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, lwjgl

So I'm using gluProject to take the 3d coordinates and tell me where on the screen they rendered. The problem is I don't get the same coordinates with gluProject and where they actually ended up rendering. The weird part is that if the difference between the x, y, and z of the camera and the point i'm testing are equal (e.g. camera at 5,3,4 and point at 2,0,1) it gives the correct values. I'm using gluLookAt() for camera transforms. I have confirmed that the same matrices that I use for rendering are being passed in to gluProject. Below is my rendering code, camera.look(), and my part with gluProject:

Rendering:

```
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glViewport(0, 0, Display.getHeight(), Display.getHeight());
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(90.0f, 1, .1f, 1000f);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
cam.look();
for (Cube cube : cubes) {
    cube.draw();
}
grid.draw();
```

Camera.look():

```
void look() {
    calcPoints(xAng, yAng);
    gluLookAt(x, y, z, x + dx, y + dy, z + dz, 0, 1, 0);
}
```

part with gluProject:

```
glViewport(0, 0, Display.getHeight(), Display.getHeight());
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(90.0f, 1, .1f, 1000f);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
cam.look();

modelview = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16); //floatbuffers, defined earlier
projection = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
viewport = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(16);
FloatBuffer result = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(3);

glGetFloat(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview);
glGetFloat(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection);
glGetInteger(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);

gluProject(1f, 0f, 0f, modelview, projection, viewport, result);
//Utils.printFloatBuffer(projection);
//Utils.printFloatBuffer(modelview);
System.out.println(result.get(0) + " " + result.get(1) + " " + result.get(2));
```

Comment: Not sure if this would matter but you don't need 16 entries for the viewport, 4 is all it returns (starting x and y then width and height).

Comment: Oh man , we are in the year 2013 and you are still using fixed pipeline?Use the modern approach and then it is up to you how your projection matrix looks like...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try having the up vector at a right angle to the camera direction and position instead of (0, 1, 0) constantly.

Comment: Why would that help? The up vector designates which direction is up, so if I change that my view will rotate.